# Error when using OleDB or ODBC in C# application

Tags: c#, odbc, oledb

I have a windows application and I have this code:

```
private void saveToDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save the DataSet Appointments table to the database.
    KaznetiTableAdapter ta = new KaznetiTableAdapter();
    ta.Adapter.RowUpdated += new  OleDbRowUpdatedEventHandler(Adapter_RowUpdated);
    ta.Update(kbDataSet.Kazneti);
}

void Adapter_RowUpdated(object sender,OdbcRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RecordsAffected == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            e.Row["Adresa"].ToString()
            "Optimistic Concurrency Error - Notes Not Saved",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Warning
        );
        e.Status = UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow;
    }
}
```

I got an error message:

> Error 1   No overload for 'Adapter_RowUpdated' matches delegate 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatedEventHandler'

If I change OleDb in the bolded code in Odbc I got an error again:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcRowUpdatedEventHandler' to 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatedEventHandler'

Comment: what is `KaznetiTableAdapter` and it's `Adapter` ? can you show the code?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the error message you're getting is pretty obvious:

> *Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcRowUpdatedEventHandler' to 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatedEventHandler'*

So, change the line

```
void Adapter_RowUpdated(object sender,OdbcRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
```

to

```
void Adapter_RowUpdated(object sender,OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
```

**Edited to answer a comment**

Then I think you could try something like this:

```
ta.Adapter.RowUpdated += (sender, e) => 
{  
    if (e.RecordsAffected == 0)  
    {  
        MessageBox.Show(  
            e.Row["Adresa"].ToString()  
            "Optimistic Concurrency Error - Notes Not Saved",  
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,  
            MessageBoxIcon.Warning );  
        e.Status = UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I have already done that and I got message:
Error 1 No overload for 'Adapter_RowUpdated' matches delegate 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcRowUpdatedEventHandler'

Answer (score 1):

if you using OleDbDataAdapter

```
adapter.RowUpdating += new OleDbRowUpdatingEventHandler(OnRowUpdating);
```

create handler as

```
protected static void OnRowUpdating(object sender, 
    OleDbRowUpdatingEventArgs args)
{
   // code 
}
```

if you using SqlDataAdapter

```
adapter.RowUpdating += new SqlRowUpdatingEventHandler( OnRowUpdating );
```

create handler as

```
private static void OnRowUpdating(object sender, SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs e) 
{
      // code 
}
```

you can easily generate event on visual studio by pressing tab key twice ones you type `+=`

Answer (score 0):

I think your delegate needs to be static:

```
static void Adapter_RowUpdated(object sender,OdbcRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: if I put static in front of void nothing changes

Comment: Make sure you are using OleDbRowUpdatedEventHandler with OdbcRowUpdatedEventArgs.